# How to show only one of two conditions in IF statement (conditions separated by + )

Tags: excel, vba

I have two conditions under `True` statement in `IF`. It only works if both conditions are met. Is it possible to dismiss one of the conditions (the one not being procced) and show only good one if other doesn't return a value.

```
IF($C$12="BB";
(INDEX(PARMSETS!$AF$3:$AF$1796;MATCH(1;INDEX(($M11=PARMSETS!$AD$3:$AD$3333)*
(N$9=PARMSETS!$AE$3:$AE$3333););0))+
(INDEX(PARMSETS!$AF$3:$AF$1796;MATCH(1;INDEX(($M11=PARMSETS!$AD$3:$AD$3333)*
("M_F_S"=PARMSETS!$AB$3:$AB$3333););0))))
```

Comment: Wouldn't a nested IF-statement work for that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is not clear (to me?) what you are asking. Can you make a shorter example to let us understand what you need?

Comment: It is possible with nested `IF` but we are so confused with your formula because there's only one statement as opposed to two, which you were saying. Also, there's a flaw with your formula that you didn't close the `IF` statement with `)`.

Comment: Ha, will try to simplify it. `IF(`A1=1`;`(`A3+A4`)`+`(`A5+A6`)``;`""`). Imagine only value for A3 is missing, despite that, I'm fine with seeing result from (A4)+(A5+A6). With current setup, if (A3 is missign) it returns NA

Comment: *if (A3 is missign) it returns NA* what do you mean with *missing*? If `A3` is empty, it will return 0, so the calculation would be `0+A4+A5+A6`

Comment: As you can see, actual formula is more complex. In my case A3 is returned as N/A. Which leads to the additon of N/A + (A5+A6). tThat's my question, is it possible to exclude (A3+A4) in case it is beeing returned as N/A

Comment: [`IFERROR`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-C526FD07-CAEB-47B8-8BB6-63F3E417F611)? BTW, it is usually better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55727001/edit) instead of adding a lot of hard to parse information in comments